# The main thread is blocked by the redrawing by update() on qwidget causing the detection of Qkeyevent to be delayed in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

I am creating a text editor application using Qt. This application needs to update many texts in the area.

I investigated the application performance and found that increasing the application window size significantly reduced the key repeat rate. That is, for example, the operation of scrolling the drawing area by continuing to input a key becomes extremely slow as the application window size increases. The cause of this problem is that the [Update()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) function itself, which updates the entire application widget, appears to have a significant effect, rather than the cost of a lot of text rendering.

I wrote a simple application to check this problem.
This application draws a random rectangle on the application by any key input, and outputs the key repeat rate to the standard output.

https://github.com/akiyosi/testguiapp/blob/master/main.go

This drawing speed (that is, the speed of key repeat) decays as the application window size increases. 
On my laptop (MacBook Pro Late 2013), the application can achieve 60fps with window size less than one-third of the screen, but attenuates to about 40fps with more than half of the screen.

Is there a way to keep the key repeat rate unaffected by the widget's [Update()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update)?

Comment: Are you sure that this is Qt related problem?

Comment: I'm not sure that, but I would like to know if there is a way to mitigate the decay of the key repeat rate due to call `Update()`